# Invalid DN syntax for active directory Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script to add users to a security group automatically that is throwing me an error. Here is the relevant code:

```
$tmp = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$user'"
Write-Host "User DN name -> " $tmp.DistinguishedName
$group.Add("LDAP://$($tmp.DistinguishedName)")
$group.CommitChanges()
```

And here is the output:

```
User DN name ->  CN=Test\, Test2,OU=Users,OU=my_location,OU=CP,OU=_Divisions,DC=my_domain,DC=my_domain
An error occurred: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Add": "An invalid 
dn syntax has been specified."
```

I assume it has something to do with the fact that there is a comma in my user's common name, but I thought that the backslash would escape that character. Any help is appreciated, this is just a side project so no pressure to finish it!

Comment: you seem to have the AD Module available to you so why not use `Add-ADGroupMember`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced:

```
$group.Add("LDAP://$($tmp.DistinguishedName)")
$group.CommitChanges()
```

With:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $tmp
```

And it worked. Thank you to @SantiagoSquarzon for the help answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `adsi` and `adsisearcher` for some reason, like you wouldn't have the Active Directory Module available to you, you can do the following:

```bash
$group = 'mygroupsamhere'
$user = 'john.doe'
$group = [adsisearcher]::new("(samAccountName=$group)").FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
$user = [adsisearcher]::new("(samAccountName=$user)").FindOne()
$null = $group.Add($user.Path)
```